# parameters of createUser method in samlJitHandler

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, saml, jit-handler

the syntax of createUser method in samlJitHandler class is

```
 createUser(Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId,String federationIdentifier,
             Map<String, String> attributes, String assertion)
```

I understand that this method gets invoked automatically but I could not figure how the parameters `String attributes, String assertion,String federationIdentifier,String communityId...` are getting  passed to this method.

Please help me in understanding this flow.